# group generated by (1234) and (3456)

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $S_6$ which is generated by $(1234)$ and $(3456)$.

I wrote a script and found that the order of $G$ is 120. But which group is $G$?

Answer (score 3):

It's ${\rm PGL}(2,5)$. This arises as the permutations on the corner pieces of a Rubik's Cube that you get when you just do turns of two adjacent faces.

This permutation group is equivalent to the natural representation of ${\rm PGL}(2,5)$ on the six points of the projective line over the field of order 5. It is also worth noting that ${\rm PGL}(2,5) \cong S_5$.

Comment: I think it's worth noting this group is also isomorphic to $S_5$.

Comment: @JoshB. Yes I agree!